# Error when loading XML with MonoGame's Content Manager

Tags: c#, xml, monogame

I'm trying to try out GeonBit.UI and when I go to build the project the ContentManager gives me this error for every XML file:

```
[PROJECT DIRECTORY]/Content/GeonBit.UI/themes/lowres/textures/slider_fancy_md.xml : error : Importer 'XmlImporter' had unexpected failure!
  System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
     at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__23`3.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Intermediate.IntermediateSerializer.FindType(String typeName)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Intermediate.IntermediateReader.ReadObject[T](ContentSerializerAttribute format, ContentTypeSerializer typeSerializer, T existingInstance)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Intermediate.IntermediateReader.ReadObject[T](ContentSerializerAttribute format)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Intermediate.IntermediateSerializer.Deserialize[T](XmlReader input, String referenceRelocationPath)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.XmlImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context)
     at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentImporter`1.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentImporter.Import(String filename, ContentImporterContext context)
     at MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Builder.PipelineManager.ProcessContent(PipelineBuildEvent pipelineEvent)
```

I'm pretty sure it's with MonoGame (3.7.1) because it happens with non-GeonBit.UI XML's also.
Is there a fix for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer on [community.monogame.net](http://community.monogame.net/t/content-builder-cant-find-any-custom-font-files-when-building/11504/2?u=evglabs)

> When this happens, you can drop the .ttf file next to the .spritefont file and the Content Pipeline will find it. You don't need to actually add the .ttf to the content project, it just needs to live next to t the spritefont.